# Call constructor from "abstract" base "class"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following requirements:

- My "super" "class" has to be "abstract"
- The constructor of my "super" "class" has to be called by the inherited class
- The constructor of the inherited "class" has to do some stuff ...

I tried it that way:

```
var Father = function() {
    if(this.constructor === Father) {
        // ...I throw an exception here to make it "abstract"...
    }
    alert('Father constructor');
};
Father.prototype.say = function() {
    alert('Im your father');
};

var Son = function() {
    Father.call(this);
    alert('Son constructor');
};
Son.prototype = Object.create(Father.prototype);

var son = new Son();
son.say();
```

With `this.constructor === Father` I try to implement `Father` as "abstract" "class" (if it's true, I'm throwing an error in my real code).

`Father.call(this);` ensures that the constructor of my super class is called. But then `this.constructor === Father`  is true.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not setting the `constructor` property correctly when doing the derivation. After this line:

```
Son.prototype = Object.create(Father.prototype);
```

you need

```
Son.prototype.constructor = Son;
```

That's just part of the boilerplate for doing this kind of inheritance with constructor functions. Without it, `Son.prototype` inherits the `Father.prototype.constructor` property which was set by the JavaScript engine when it created the `Father` function. You have to do it explicitly for `Son` because you're *replacing* the object on `Son.prototype` (which is the correct thing to do, you just need to then do this `constructor` fixup).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I guess I have to dig deeper to the "magic" of JS. And yes, your update was right. That was a typo.

Comment: @mosquito87: You got all the other bits of the inheritance right (and a lot of people don't), this is one of the bits lots of people forget and leave out (since JavaScript itself doesn't actually *use* the `constructor` property for anything, even though it creates it).

Comment: I use this construction: `Son.prototype = Object.create(Father.prototype, { constructor: { value: Son } });`

Comment: @micnic: Good one. Yeah, that works if you don't need to shim `Object.create` (as the two-argument form can't be shimmed properly). Also note that you're making `constructor` both non-writeable and non-configurable, which is different from [what the JavaScript engine does](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) (Step 17) (I think one could argue that non-writeable and non-configurable make good sense, just thought I would flag the difference).